# Testing an intervention by repeated measure of opinion before and after the intervention

Tags: frequency, many-categories, intervention-analysis

How can we test the null hypothesis that an intervention has no effect on opinions for 44 people. These opinions were measured as frequencies in 3 categories (A, B, C) before and after the intervention. 
Before
A=20. B=18. C=6
After
A=24. B=12. C=8
The individual before-after changes were:
A-A 19
A-C 1
B-A 4
B-B 10
B-C 4
C-A 1
C-B 2
C-C 3

Comment: What is the nature of these three categories? Are you referring to a situation where 1 of 3 possible things can happen, or are these three different (unlimited) counts? Something else?

Comment: These counts don't provide enough information.  Because your objective is to assess "effect on opinions ... of people," you must keep track of the before- and after- opinions of each individual.  Otherwise all you get is a summary of opinions within the *group.*

Answer (score 0):

I found this possible answer on page 120 of "Statistical methods for rates and proportions", second edition, by J.L Fleiss:

In the case when we have 3 levels (say "d","n","a"), the stuart-maxwell test can be calculated from the contingency table of responses before and after the intervention:

```
After =     d    n    a   
Before                    Total Before
   d       Ndd  Ndn  Nda    Nd.
   n       Nnd  Nnn  Nna    Nn.
   a       Nad  Nan  Naa    Na.
```

Total After   N.d  N.n  N.a    N..

Define      NAVGij = (Nij + Nji) /2, and
            DIFFd = (Nd. – N.d), 
            DIFFn = (Nn. – N.n), 
            DIFFa = (Na. – N.a)

Our test statistic with Chi-squared 2 degrees of freedom is calculated:

( NAVGna * (DIFFd)^2 + NAVGda * (DIFFn)^2 + NAVGdn * (DIFFa)^2) / 
                   (2*(NAVGdn * NAVGda + NAVGdn * NAVGna + NAVGda * NAVGna))

[with apologies for the lack of proper mathematical notation]